# Does description change impact the google ranking and/or crawl rates?

Tags: seo, google, ranking, google-ranking, crawl-rate

I am thinking about adding some randomization to my shopping cart descriptions and pricing. 
I am not talking about meta-description, but about actual product descriptions.

Would content change improve any of my stats with google? I am especially interested in crawl rates.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about product description then unique content can give positive SEO benefits rather than 100 products with the same description which will be viewed as duplicate content.

If you are talking about meta descriptions... ([from this post](http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/meta-description))

> **Not a Google Ranking Factor**
>
> Google announced in September of 2009 that neither meta descriptions
>   nor meta keywords factor into Google's ranking algorithms for web
>   search. Google uses meta descriptions to return results when searchers
>   use advanced search operators to match meta tag content, as well as to
>   pull preview snippets on search result pages, but it's important to
>   note that meta descriptions do not to influence Google's ranking
>   algorithms for normal web search.

Comment: It doesn't sound like they were talking about the meta description but the product description.

Comment: (Perhaps off-topic, but... since I found this post whilst searching on the meta description...) Regarding the meta description, Google also mentioned this in a [blog post from Sept 2007](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2007/09/improve-snippets-with-meta-description.html): "...it's worth noting that while accurate meta descriptions can improve clickthrough, they won't affect your ranking within search results."

Answer (score 0):

If Google hasn't indexed your product pages in a while it's most likely they've begun to slow down their indexing and crawling of your product pages. Updating your product descriptions will update the pages and when Google comes back they'll see the page has been recently updated and then they'll decide what to do with it. No guarantee it's going to increase your rankings or crawl rate. But surely having well written product descriptions will help. You should also think about setting up product features and listing them on the product page if you already have them see if you can come up with more. Search for the same products on Google and see what other sites are writing about them and using for product features. Don't copy them just get some ideas on what to write about and list as features.